# Simple question about #import

Tags: c++, programming-languages

Is #import or #include a job that is handled by the complier or by the linker?

Comment: #import isn't part of C++, tags are off.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anything that starts with `#` is a preprocessor directive and is expanded by the preprocessor, which is a step that happens before compilation.

Comment: Modern compilers usually integrate a preprocessor, but for the purpose of analysis and specification, you can still treat them separately.

Answer (score 4):

preprocessor -> compiler -> linker

`#` is handled by first - preprocessor

Comment: and lexer, parser, and assembler :-)

Comment: i mentioned major and independent steps. optimizer, lexer, parser etc are parts of compiler